# Так надолго / На так долго

Tags: порядок-слов

Правомерны оба варианта?

> Так надолго задерживать грузы.
>
> На так долго задерживать грузы.

Answer (score 1):

Второй вариант явно хуже, в книгах почти не встречается. Но и первый имеет разговорный оттенок, хотя и типичен для книжек последних двух-трёх лет. Лучше добавить пару букв и написать: *задерживать грузы **на столь долгий срок***.

Comment: Alex_ander, второй вариант явно хуже? А он вообще-то нормативный? С чего бы это предлог у нас относится к наречию?  И правилен ли такой вариант: на долго задерживать грузы.

Comment: А здесь правильно? "Бросив пить ( на долго ли? ), я удивительно остро стал чувствовать жизнь. Даст ли это что-нибудь для творчества? "[Ю. М. Нагибин. Дневник (1968)]

Comment: Попался в одной печатной книжке, поэтому не хотелось сразу "убивать". Заглянул ещё раз: предлог "на" там от другой части предложения примкнул. Для меня и первый вариант нескладно выглядит. Задерживать грузы (как и "затягивать с" любыми действиями) можно "надолго" или "настолько". В "дневнике" правильнее "надолго ли".

Comment: Да, я тоже так думаю.Но в Нацкорпусе для формы "на долго" больше 100 примеров, что меня очень удивляет. Попробую задать вопрос на форуме.

Comment: Из 99 примеров коллекции заметная часть происходит из форумов (напр. вся первая страница), в ряде примеров предлог "на" относится к существительному с причастием. И ещё можно всю современную журналистику отбросить (её почти не контролируют).